# When converting images into a video, does ffmpeg require input files to match a single argument?

Tags: command-line, video, ffmpeg

Does ffmpeg require images being input to match a single argument, when converting a series of images into a video?

The FAQ [3.2 How do I encode single pictures into movies?](https://www.ffmpeg.org/faq.html#How-do-I-encode-single-pictures-into-movies_003f) seems to suggest that's the case with

> First, rename your pictures to follow a numerical sequence. For example, img1.jpg, img2.jpg, img3.jpg,...

It also mentions using `cat` and `image2pipe`, but that's not very appealing.

as does the Wikibooks entry [FFMPEG_An_Intermediate_Guide/image_sequence](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/FFMPEG_An_Intermediate_Guide/image_sequence#Filename_patterns), even though you can pass in a glob.

It seems odd that I can't just tell it the name of each input file individually.

Related question: [How to provide multiple input to ffmpeg?](https://superuser.com/questions/242584/how-to-provide-multiple-input-to-ffmpeg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can list each input individually:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -t 4 -i 001.png -loop 1 -t 2 -i 002.png -loop 1 -t 3 -i 003.png \
-filter_complex "[0][1][2]concat=n=3:v=1:a=0" output.foo
```

I assumed you want to concatenate the images, so I added the [concat filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#concat). Alternatively, you could use the [concat demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat).